# Bash assign variable using another variable

Tags: bash, variables, variable-assignment

I'm not exactly sure how to word the title, but what I am trying to do is to set `username` to `$DEV_ENVIRONMENT`, `$STAGE_ENVIRONMENT`, or `$PROD_ENVIRONMENT` respectively, each of which is defined in my properties file.

My function would take in one argument (`DEV`, `STAGE`, or `PROD`) and check the hostname against the edges defined in `$_ENVIRONMENT`.

```
while IFS=',' read -ra line
do
        for i in "${line[@]}"
        do
                if [ $(hostname) = $i ]
                then
                        username="$1"_USERNAME
                        break
                fi
        done
done <<< "${1}_ENVIRONMENT"
```

So for instance, if I pass in `DEV`, then I would like `username` set to `$DEV_USERNAME` and I'd like the `while` loop to search through the nodes defined in `$DEV_ENVIRONMENT`, both of which would be values read in from my properties file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash supports [indirection expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#indirection), so you can do:

```
var=${1}_ENVIRONMENT
username=${!var}
```

rather than the slightly more cumbersome and potentially dangerous eval:

```
eval username=\$${1}_ENVIRONMENT
```

So for your code:

```
while IFS=',' read -ra line
do
        for i in "${line[@]}"
        do
                if [ $(hostname) = $i ]
                then
                        var="$1"_USERNAME
                        username=${!var}
                        break
                fi
        done
done <<< "${1}_ENVIRONMENT"
```

Comment: Perfect! I'll accept your answer when it allows me, but would you mind expanding on the dangers of using the `eval` example you posted?

Comment: I was going to suggest eval or declare, but this solution works better.

Comment: eval allows you do do anything in the statement, so you could, for example have `var="; echo evil"; eval user=\$$var` would echo `evil` i.e. it's subject to value injection.

Comment: The eval command is extremely powerful and extremely easy to abuse. [Examples of bad use of eval](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)

Comment: BashFAQ #006 -- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006 -- might be another worthwhile reference.

Comment: Yikes, I think I used `eval` in another script. Going to go back and fix it. Thanks for the heads up!